# How to set to 1 the lower 3 bits of a character?

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64

I'm using `x86_64 Linux Assembly` and I'm asked to set to 1 the three lower bits of a character (from user input) and then print the resulting character. To illustrate

```
Input: b        ; ASCII in binary: 01100010

Set the last 3 bits to 1:

01100010 -> 01100111

Output: g       ; ASCII in binary: 01100111
```

As far as I understand, the input character is already taken as binary in Assembly. So my question is:

Is there a way to get the binary form of the character? If so, I'll be glad if somebody could provide a pseudocode.

So far the only thing that came to my mind was to convert the ASCII character of the input character to integer `->` convert to binary `->` set to one the lower 3 bits `->` pass from binary to integer `->` convert to string `->` print. But I haven't thought too much about this way, since it's clear that it looks quite tedious.

Comment: Show us what you have tried, a [MCVE] to demonstrate.

Comment: `bits` or `bytes` - there are no bites. Unless you are biting something.

Comment: @t0mm13b My only attempt was the one I've described above about converting the ASCII code to integer. You can imagine how many lines of code that example would be (without considering the workaround with the set-to-one-the-lower-3-bits part). That's the reason why I'm not posting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a character in your program, it is already in the form you need. There is no conversion and no difference between “character form,” “integer form,” and “binary form.” For example, ASCII `b` is represented by the number 98. When you load the character `b` into the register `al`, that's the same thing as loading the number 98 into `al`.

Lastly, to turn bits on, use the `or` instruction. For example, if your character is in `al`, you can turn on the lowest three bits using

```
or al, 7
```